# Weird behavior across site with css styles

Tags: css

Okay I have been dealing with this problem for a while now and was honestly hesitating on coming here to see what the problem is. I am almost positive it is either a specificity issue, my work around for caching problem is causing or somewhere I am messing up. Okay first what I noticed is that I was suffering from a caching problem and new styles weren't being applied(which was never a problem till my last two projects). So, I found a solution on here that says to add:

```
?<?php echo time() ?>
```

to the end of the css url for my link tags example:

```
<link href="styles.css<?php echo time();?>
```

That worked like a charm to stop the caching issue, but since doing that I have been seeing odd behaviors. Like for instance certain styles not applying even tho I use the right class/id. I use a mix of tag selectors and class selectors(this is probably the specificity issue comes into play if one). I had just recently observed where the same color being two different colors on two different pages. The only way I was able to fix that was using inline styling. Yes that is another thing I have notice on some pages even tho linked correctly the external style sheet wont apply styles to new page where I am using the same class names that are referenced in the external stylesheet to where I have to use internal styling and sometimes that doesn't work(doesn't apply styles to what I am telling it too) and have to use inline styling. I have never experienced this behavior so that is why I am thinking either my work around for caching problem or it is a specificity issue.

http://www.skillersrealm.com/includes/css/style.css

http://www.skillersrealm.com/includes/css/nav.css

I was finally able to recreate the problem example...

I moved all the internal styles to an external stylesheet and this is a perfect example where some get applied and some don't(styles). Oh whether I use the caching workaround or not it is the same result.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2pyI.jpg

Added the css back internally and then all the styles applied again.

This is how it is suppose to look:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRVcF.jpg

Comment: I didn't include css code because to much and don't know where the problem area lies to condense to that part. If asked will include

Comment: Your example is wrong. It should read: `<link href="styles.css?<?php echo time();?>" />`. In web design, quotes are extremely important. This might or might not fix your issue, but, since I noticed it, I thought I'd point it out.

Comment: You can't supply any SO required code so we have nothing to work with. Therefore, I voted to close this question for those reasons except should Andrei's solution solves it. @AndreiGheorghiu the `<link>` tag does not use or need a closing slash.

Comment: You are required to post your code here, not your site which will change or disappear: [mcve] Posting only the CSS means next to nothing.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Good question but I don't recall what PHP does with quotes there.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu If you have a question of your own, start your own topic.

Comment: Wow, I didnt include any because I dont know how to condese it because that is what you would of told. To much code.

Comment: And I rewrote that and forgot to put the quote. In the code it has the quote.

Comment: Part of problem solving is what we would have to do if you don't do the work; narrowing down the code to where the exact problem is. You narrow it down and, if you still can't figure it out, then come to us. Don't ask us to clear the path for you.

Comment: @Rob, I don't have a question, I'm the one with the answers. Regarding your remark on ending slashes, they're not needed in HTML, but needed in XHTML. Since I can't know the declared doctype, while on [so] I'll use ending slashes for void tags in my answers and suggestions, if you don't mind. They don't do any harm in HTML.

Comment: I can guarantee you @AndreiGheorghiu that he is not using XHTML and, therefore, the closing slash is pointless.

Comment: I am using html5 doctype. I wouldn't even know where to start narrowing down because I don't know what the problem specifically is.

Answer (score 0):

Your "solution" to caching prevents page caching to work every time, which is not really a good solution to start with. Rather use a header/comment update in your CSS file (CSS versioning number or similar) when making updates, to force update only when actually needed.

What comes to certain pages not loading properly, is it possible the whole page is already cached when you click it and the page does not load your "forced cache" CSS hack? Or maybe you are creating some dynamic content where CSS does not get applied properly? Are you certain it's only certain CSS styles that do not apply when this "bug" occurs and it happens only after you update your CSS?

*P.s if you have a lot of small color changes or similar happening in your pages all the time, make two CSS files. One "permanent" and minimized for your "static" objects and load only the smaller changes from other file. Or go with SAS/LESS.*

Comment: You should maybe debug this by doing minor changes and test with (forced) caching  on and off to see if there is a difference. Without knowing your page structure and how they are generated it's only guesswork. But it does sound like you could gain from using a LESS compiler.

Comment: Appending a random sequence (or timestamp) as version of a file works quite well for disabling cache while developing. If you develop with cache you lose more time having to refresh multiple times to see the changes than you lose from not caching in the first place. Of course, there are other ways to disable cache-ing, but developing with cache enabled is a clear sign of not being a decent developer, IMHO.

Comment: I can answer the page structure and how they are generated. What do you wanna know

Comment: I never turned it on. I don't mess with web browser settings ever. Except to delete temp and history files

Comment: For development phase it's perfectly fine to disable caching or load all pages locally, but it seems many people let this "fix" into published products and it's not really the best way to go, even thou it matters very little with smaller sites/few pages/few users/hits.

Comment: oh your ps is true alot of color changes or same changes happening which leads to a possible specificity issue

Comment: As you are not sure when your changes are not properly loaded it's hard to guide you, hence I suggested you do only one small change and refresh your page(s) with and without your cache to see if you can recreate the problem in any specific page which could give you some hints what causes the problem. From my experiences it's either cached old CSS loaded, no CSS loaded at all or some dynamic creator failing to ID/CLASS element properly when things like this happen.

Comment: Well I notice when styles aren't being applied they are cross off in developer. So that leads me to believe it is being ignored by browser in favor of another rule or similar behavior

Comment: also I just realized what you meant by "dynamic content". Yes these issues happen when I try to apply classes to dynamically added content. language is php if you need to know

Comment: I found with my reproducing the problems is that the css file responsible for styling that page isn't even showing up in the network section of the chrome developer

Comment: Is it showing in the debugger elements -section in the HTML header?

Comment: WHat do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155808/discussion-between-daniel-johanson-and-stacking-for-heap).

Answer (score 0):

I have broke it down to it being the caching hack being the problem. The example that I used above to simulate the behavior isn't accurate because I put src instead of href in my link tag. Fingers crossed that I will no longer have issues. Long story short I am pretty sure that the caching hack I was using was causing the issues.

Comment: I hope you got it solved. If not, be extra careful with any dynamic content and tags and make sure all pages actually load some sort of CSS. For long run sustainability, make my suggested 2nd CSS file for minor changes or (more recommended really) import LESS and use variables for color names. If you are not familiar with LESS yet, you can learn the basics in two hours easily with some effort.

Comment: Yeah I am thinking of going with less for real. Still having issues of some sort. Like I am experience on color, same color value, being two different colors on two different pages. The only way to get to change the right color is to put it into the tag itself(inline styling)